# Does pairwise logical independence imply mutual logical independence?

Tags: logic

- Let two statements $A, B$ be *logically independent* iff $A\not\models B, B \not\models A, A\not\models \neg B, B \not\models \neg A$.
- Let a set $S$ of statements be *pairwise logically independent* iff for any $A,B \in S$ with $A\neq B$, $A$ and $B$ are logically independent.
- Let a set $S$ of statements be *mutually logically independent* iff for any $S', S'' \subset S$ with $S',S'' \neq \emptyset$ and $S'\cap S'' = \emptyset$, $\bigwedge S'$ and $\bigwedge S''$ are logically independent.

Does pairwise logical independence imply mutual logical independence?

Comment: doesn't the usual probability example work? let $x,y$ be variables (say) in the reals, and let $A$ be the statement $x=0$, $B$ be the statement $y=0$, and $C$ be the statement $x+y=0$. then $\{A,B,C\}$ is pairwise independent but not mutually independent

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider (for any two independent $A,B$) setting $$C:=A\leftrightarrow B.$$ (It's a good exercise to generalize this to arbitrary sizes of sets: show that for any $n>2$ there is a non-mutually-independent set of $n$ sentences such that any size-$n-1$ subset is mutually independent.)